# Facebook App Being Throttled

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, throttling

I'm working with an app which has suddenly (within the past week or so) started receiving the following response back when making any API request:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#4) Application request limit reached",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 4
   }
}
```

I was under the impression that the API limit was per auth token, per IP, but once this starts happening, it affects everyone using the app. Under the Developer Insights, I see:

```
Restrictions
App is unrestricted.

API Throttling  - 21 hours, 42 minutes

Too Many Calls  - 21 hours, 42 minutes
Method  Fraction of Budget
gr:get:User/home    441%
gr:get:Post/likes   145%
gr:get:User/feed    107%
gr:get:/fql 65%
gr:get:User/inbox   51%
gr:get:Post 26%
gr:get:User/events  20%
gr:get:User/notifications   18%
gr:get:Page/feed    18%
gr:get:ObjectComment    4.6%

Calls Are Too CPU Intensive  - 21 hours, 2 minutes
Method  Fraction of Budget
gr:get:User/home    3.5k%
gr:get:User/feed    382%
gr:get:Page/feed    205%
gr:get:Post/likes   106%
gr:get:User/inbox   63%
gr:get:/fql 40%
gr:get:User/notifications   25%
gr:get:Post 16%
gr:get:User/events  7.4%
gr:get:ObjectComment    3.2%

Calls Access Too Much Data  - 7 hours, 57 minutes
Method  Fraction of Budget
gr:get:User/home    372%
gr:get:User/feed    11%
gr:get:User/notifications   3.5%
gr:get:/fql 1.7%
gr:get:User/inbox   1.1%
gr:get:User/events  0.19%
gr:get:Post 0.07%
gr:get:Thread   0.04%
gr:get:Status   0.03%
dialog:oauth    0.03%

API Throttling Warnings  - 21 hours, 42 minutes

Too Many Calls  - 21 hours, 42 minutes
Method  Fraction of Budget
gr:get:User/home    882%
gr:get:Post/likes   291%
gr:get:User/feed    215%
gr:get:/fql 129%
gr:get:User/inbox   101%
gr:get:Post 52%
gr:get:User/events  40%
gr:get:User/notifications   37%
gr:get:Page/feed    35%
gr:get:ObjectComment    9.3%

Calls Are Too CPU Intensive  - 21 hours, 42 minutes
Method  Fraction of Budget
gr:get:User/home    7.1k%
gr:get:User/feed    742%
gr:get:Page/feed    410%
gr:get:Post/likes   213%
gr:get:User/inbox   124%
gr:get:/fql 78%
gr:get:User/notifications   49%
gr:get:Post 42%
gr:get:User/events  15%
gr:get:ObjectComment    6.3%

Calls Access Too Much Data  - 12 hours, 45 minutes
Method  Fraction of Budget
gr:get:User/home    715%
gr:get:User/feed    64%
gr:get:Page/feed    30%
gr:get:User/notifications   9.1%
gr:get:/fql 7.4%
gr:get:User/inbox   6.4%
gr:get:Post 2.2%
gr:get:User/events  0.64%
dialog:optin    0.16%
gr:get:Thread   0.07%
```

Clearly I'm doing something that FB doesn't like, and it's throttling access from my app. I only access FB every 300 seconds. Is that too often? I'm trying to take advantage of the real time updates, but the updates I get are sporadic; they don't always come through, even when I see the official Facebook site update. So if I don't find any real time updates within 5 minutes, I just grab the latest data from FB.

When it works, my app works well. But I, and my users, encounter this limiting error at least once a day. When I was developing the app, and had only a handful of testers, we never ran into this problem. It's only been since the app has been made available to more users that it's become an issue.

I wish the limits that could cause throttling were clearly documented somewhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you're fetching /me/home too often which is using way, way too much CPU time - are you constantly polling in a loop or something?

Comment: Originally, yes. Now I'm using the real time updates. The problem is that the real time updates are hit and miss. I can watch updates fly by on facebook.com for my own account, but my server rarely gets updates for my uid, except for when I post to my own wall. So, in my app, I say if I don't get anything from real time updates after 5 minutes, grab /me/home directly. If real time updates worked, I wouldn't need to do this, but I don't see any other way. I'm open to suggestions. Thanks!